# Grails - JSON binding causing JSONException

Tags: json, grails, groovy

I have the following controller code:

```
def save(MyModel model) {
    model.save()
}
```

And I'm testing it using:

```
//e.g. 2ff59e55-ee3d-4f66-8bfa-00f355f52c49
def uuid = UUID.randomUUID.toString()
controller.request.contentType = JSON_CONTENT_TYPE
controller.request.method = 'POST'
controller.request.json = "{'uuid': '$uuid', 'description': 'test object', 'count': 1}"
controller.save()
```

However, every time I run the test I get,

```
org.apache.commons.lang.UnhandledException:
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.exceptions.ConverterException:
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONException: Value out of sequence: expected mode to be
OBJECT or ARRAY when writing '{'uuid': '2ff59e55-ee3d-4f66-8bfa-00f355f52c49', 'description': 'test object', 'count': 1}' but was INIT
```

Comment: `String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString()` and `/{'uuid': "$uuid", 'description': 'test object'}/`. Use slashy String in order to use `"` for GString.

Comment: Oops. I updated the question to correct the `uuid` part; it was just a typo. I tested again with the GString delimited by `/.../` but I'm still getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON converter chokes on Groovy Strings.  I've solved this by slapping a `.toString()` on the end: `"{'uuid':'$uuid'}".toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
void "Test the save action correctly persists an instance"() {
    when:
    Integer originalCount = MyModel.count()
    String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
    controller.request.contentType = 'application/json'
    controller.request.method = 'POST'
    controller.request.json = ['uuid': uuid, 'description': 'test object'] as JSON
    controller.save()

    then:
    assert originalCount + 1 == MyModel.count()
}
```

Comment: This worked using `grails.converters.JSON`. There was another `JSON` type option but I did not try it anymore because the one I mentioned worked on my first try. I'm familiar with the `as` keyword, but I'm curious why the `GString` wouldn't work and this one would...

Comment: Ok, so while it does not generate the error, it's not setting the properties either. Actually it looks like JSON binding isn't working at all, even just using `{'description': 'test object'}` does not set the `description` property.

Comment: I have updated my answer. It is passing. Assert statement pass that means we have one more entry in MyModel.

Comment: And for your first comment question, I don't have reason for that but `"{'uuid':" + uuid + ", 'description': 'test object'}"` is also working..,.

Comment: The updated test code looks pretty similar to what I have, and it's passing (i.e. the count gets updated). However, the model in the controller does not have any data in it. For example, `model.description` is null. What version of Grails are you testing this with?

Comment: I am using `grails 2.3.5` and if I print the model instance property in the controller then I am getting the data. `println "====${model.description}====${model.uuid}==${model.id}===="` and output is `===test object====bb86fc6c-9101-4910-bdef-410e583cf120==1===`.