# Grails - Do you still need parseRequest for JSON binding to work in controller?

Tags: json, grails

Ok, this is my Nth question regarding this topic, and I'm getting really frustrated with Grails. Please have a quick look on [one of my earlier questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040673/grails-json-binding-causing-jsonexception/24043971) for more details.

Among other things, my problem is that sending JSON formatted data to the controller when testing doesn't seem to work. The controller doesn't get null object, but the argument passed is practically empty--the JSON properties don't get set.

Aside from the controller code from the link above, I also tried,

```
def save() {
    def model = new MyModel(request.JSON)
    model.save()
}
```

but it still fails to set properties.

From my Web searches, I read that in older versions, `parseRequest` must be set to `true` in `UrlMapping.groovy` so that request data formatted in XML, JSON, etc. would automatically be parsed and passed as controller method argument. I'm working on Grails 2.3.9, and I'm not sure if it's still necessary to do that.

The time I thought I'd save if I use Grails on this project is being spent on looking for an answer to this seemingly simple task of testing a RESTful Web service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No since 2.3.0 the parseRequest option doesn't do anything. The request is parsed lazily only when request.XML or request.JSON is accessed or when binding to a command object.

Comment: Then why is it not working when I'm doing the tests?

Comment: @PsychoPunch The answer to that question (the question in the comment above, not the original question) probably depends on what your test and the code you are testing looks like.

Comment: The code in the question I linked is what the code looks like. Not sure if I should copy it here.

Comment: I created a new Grails app, tested the same code, and it worked. I don't know why.